# Long numbers are being transformed into scientific notation when saved in the database pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that i have transformed in before loading it to a table, the problem is that one of the colums contains number with +15 digts, when i use

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep="delimiter", delimiter=";", encoding="utf-8", error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype=object)
```

this is how the data is loaded
[image]

but when i check the file that is being loaded it shows the preview as scientific notation, but if i open it, it show the real value

[image]

i have tried many things.

set options in pandas `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)` did not work

used to_string `df['column'].to_string(float_format='{:.0f}'.format)` did not work

map the values `df['column'].map(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))` did not work

load the file with another float_format `float_format='%.15f'` did not work

How can i save the values without the scientific notation into the csv file?

The values in the csv file comes in scientific notation
[image]

the dtype of the column is `Name: column, Length: 11743, dtype: object`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is the current dtype of that column?

Comment: Also, it looks like you're using Excel to interpret the CSV file (per screenshot). Excel is applying a format mask over the values, which it's interpreting as large numeric values. That's normal behavior in Excel unless you take steps to override that. What does the CSV look like if you open it in a plain text editor?